# Python dictionary list unique items

Tags: python

I have below input

```
 [{"ip": "1.2.3.4", "bytes": 10}, 
  {"ip": "2.3.4.10", "bytes": 10}, 
  {"ip": "5.6.2.3", "bytes": 10},
  {"ip": "1.2.3.4", "bytes": 20}, 
  {"ip": "1.2.3.4", "bytes": 5}, 
  {"ip": "2.3.4.10", "bytes": 1},
  {"ip": "10.20.30.40", "bytes": 0}, 
  {"ip": "0.0.0.0", "bytes": 10}, 
  {"ip": "2.3.4.10", "bytes": 6}]
```

Output as unique ip address with bytes added for duplicated ip addresses

```
[{'ip': '0.0.0.0', 'bytes': 10}, 
 {'ip': '10.20.30.40', 'bytes': 0}, 
 {'ip': '2.3.4.10', 'bytes': 17}, 
 {'ip': '5.6.2.3', 'bytes': 10}, 
 {'ip': '1.2.3.4', 'bytes': 35}]
```

I wrote a code like this in Python

```
import json
logs = """[{"ip": "1.2.3.4", "bytes": 10}, {"ip": "2.3.4.10", "bytes": 10}, {"ip": "5.6.2.3", "bytes": 10},
           {"ip": "1.2.3.4", "bytes": 20}, {"ip": "1.2.3.4", "bytes": 5}, {"ip": "2.3.4.10", "bytes": 1},
           {"ip": "10.20.30.40", "bytes": 0}, {"ip": "0.0.0.0", "bytes": 10}, {"ip": "2.3.4.10", "bytes": 6}]"""

logs_json = json.loads(logs)


ips_unique = set(ip.get("ip") for ip in logs_json)


ip_unique_list = []
for ip in ips_unique:
        ip_dict = {"ip": ip, "bytes": 0}
        ip_unique_list.append(ip_dict)

for ip_unique_sep in ip_unique_list:
        for log in logs_json:
                if log["ip"] == ip_unique_sep["ip"]:
                        ip_unique_sep["bytes"] += log["bytes"]

print(ip_unique_list)
```

Is there any better and efficient way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple loop:

```
out = {}
for d in logs_json:
    if d['ip'] in out:
        out[d['ip']]['bytes'] += d['bytes']
    else:
        out[d['ip']] = d.copy()

result = list(out.values())
```

Output:

```
[{'ip': '1.2.3.4', 'bytes': 35},
 {'ip': '2.3.4.10', 'bytes': 17},
 {'ip': '5.6.2.3', 'bytes': 10},
 {'ip': '10.20.30.40', 'bytes': 0},
 {'ip': '0.0.0.0', 'bytes': 10}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) initialized with `int` (to produce zeros by default), and just loop over the parsed input and sum the bytes from the IPs. Something like:

```
result = defaultdict(int)
for item in json_logs:
    result[item.get('ip')] += item['bytes']
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
out = dict.fromkeys((x['ip'] for x in logs_json), 0)
for x in logs_json:
    out[x['ip']] += x['bytes']

out = [{'ip':ip,'bytes':bytes} for ip, bytes in out.items()]
print(out)

# Output:

[{'ip': '1.2.3.4', 'bytes': 35}, 
{'ip': '2.3.4.10', 'bytes': 17}, 
{'ip': '5.6.2.3', 'bytes': 10}, 
{'ip': '10.20.30.40', 'bytes': 0}, 
{'ip': '0.0.0.0', 'bytes': 10}]
```